# SQL Select Query via Excel VBA - Defining Parameters, query of a query

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I need to place 3 Parameters into a Select query from Excel VBA to SQL - One of which can just be replaced using a variable. But this query is a query of another query, and the parameters are held within those two other queries. If running this query in Access I'm just prompted by all three to manually type them in - "Start", "End", and "AdvisorName".

Running the code will prompt the "No value given for one or more required parameters" - However, only 1 Parameter is in this query, the other 2 parameters are held within the other two queries inside this query - "Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes" and "Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo".

The three parameters are called "Start" (Start Date range), "End" (End Date range), and "AdvisorName" (held within this query).

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Command As New ADODB.Command
Dim strSQL As String

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open ConnectionString:=Cnct
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor, 
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.KeyID,
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.SubQ_Text, 
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.CountOfAnswer AS [All], 
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.CountOfAnswer AS [No], 
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.CountOfAnswer
          AS Yes," & _"Format(Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.CountOfAnswer/
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.CountOfAnswer,'0.0%') 
          AS Result" & _" 
 FROM    (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll 
         LEFT JOIN Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo 
 ON      (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.SubQ_Text = 
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.SubQ_Text)
 AND     (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.KeyID = 
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.KeyID)
 AND     (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor = 
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.Advisor))
 LEFT JOIN Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes 
 ON     (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.SubQ_Text =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.SubQ_Text) 
 AND    (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.Advisor)
 AND    (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.KeyID =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.KeyID)" & _
        " WHERE (((Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor)=[AdvisorName]));"

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

rst.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic

rst.MoveFirst
```

The SQL for the other two queries are similar, one has a where "No" and the other a where not "No" where the parameters are required are:

```
SELECT     tbl_Surveys.Advisor, tbl_QuestionRef.KeyID, tbl_QuestionRef.CallSkill, 
           tbl_QuestionRef.CallReason, tbl_QuestionRef.MainQ_Text
           tbl_QuestionRef.SubQ_Text,
           Count(tbl_SurveyAnswers.Answer) AS CountOfAnswer
FROM       tbl_QuestionRef 
INNER JOIN (tbl_SurveyAnswers 
           INNER JOIN tbl_Surveys
           ON tbl_SurveyAnswers.SurveyLink = tbl_Surveys.ID) 
ON         tbl_QuestionRef.KeyID = tbl_SurveyAnswers.QuestionRef
WHERE      (((tbl_SurveyAnswers.Answer)<>"No" 
           And (tbl_SurveyAnswers.Answer)<>"N/A" 
           And (tbl_SurveyAnswers.Answer)<>"0") 
           AND ((tbl_Surveys.CallDate)>=[Start] 
           And (tbl_Surveys.CallDate)<=[End]))
GROUP BY   tbl_Surveys.Advisor, tbl_QuestionRef.KeyID, tbl_QuestionRef.CallSkill, 
           tbl_QuestionRef.CallReason, 
           tbl_QuestionRef.MainQ_Text, tbl_QuestionRef.SubQ_Text;
```

As you can see, the "Start" and "End" parameters are in this second SQL query... Any ideas how I can put these two parameters into the first SQL function? I can't put the Start and End into the "All" query, as it'll knock out the "Count" part...

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other two queries are saved and named, instead of calling named queries, incorporate the SQL from the two queries into the main query as derived tables. By doing so, the query will prompt for all parameters. See the JOIN clauses for some clarification.

```
strSQL = "SELECT Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor, "
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.KeyID,
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.SubQ_Text,
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.CountOfAnswer AS [All],
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.CountOfAnswer AS [No],
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.CountOfAnswer
          AS Yes," & _"Format(Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.CountOfAnswer/
          Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.CountOfAnswer,'0.0%')
          AS Result" & _"
 FROM    (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll
         LEFT JOIN (YOUR FIRST SAVE QUERY SQL) AS Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo
 ON      (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.SubQ_Text =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.SubQ_Text)
 AND     (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.KeyID =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.KeyID)
 AND     (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsNo.Advisor))
 LEFT JOIN (YOUR SECOND QUWERY SQL) AS Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes
 ON     (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.SubQ_Text =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.SubQ_Text)
 AND    (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.Advisor)
 AND    (Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.KeyID =
                Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsYes.KeyID)" & _
        " WHERE (((Q_SoloFocus_Advisor_QuestionsAll.Advisor)=[AdvisorName]));"
```